# Swift 5 - how to define struct/type as array?

Tags: swift

Say I've defined `Position` struct like this:

```
struct Movement : Codable {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
    var delay: Int
}
```

Now I want to pass around `[0,0,0]` instead of `{"x":0,"y":0,"delay":123}`. How do I define Movement as an array having exactly 3 int values?

I have an API in Swift, it receives a JSON object and needs to move the mouse. At the moment the JSON resembles `[{"x":1,"y":2,"delay":123},....]`, I want to instead send `[[1,2,123],...]` for this I want to replace the `Movement` type with something else.

Comment: Perhaps a [tuple](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID329) is what you're looking for?

Comment: `Position` already exists. It's called `CGPoint`. If you want an array drop the struct and use `[Int]`. But consider that `.x` and `.y` is much clearer to read than [0] and `[1]`.

Comment: @vadian, it's just a made up example to show what I am looking for

Comment: In the struct add a computed property `var arrayRepresentation : [Int] { return [x, y, delay] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could decode it directly into the wanted format

```
let data = #"[{"x":1,"y":2,"delay":123},{"x":2,"y":2,"delay":25}]"#.data(using: .utf8)!

let array = try! JSONDecoder().decode([[String: Int]].self, from: data)
    .map { [$0["x"]!, $0["y"]!, $0["delay"]!]}
```

This assumes the keys "x", "y" and "delay" always exist

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ExpressibleByArrayLiteral](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral), but don't. Your type is already available as [SIMD2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/simd2).

```swift
([0, 0] as SIMD2).scalarCount // 2
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a made up example, I don't have that exact type

Comment: Make up another example if you need more help with `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`.

Comment: Ok, I did do that thing

Comment: You partially did, but it's nonsensical in the current state.

Comment: Is it? I've added an explanation of why I want to do that.